# A new way to get showSnackBar

Tags: flutter

According to the updated flutter the `showSnackBar` on `currentState` is deprecated.

```
void _showSnackBar(String message) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar( // it's deprecated
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Instead, it proposes to use `ScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar();`. But if I use it then the error appears

> The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type
> 'ScaffoldMessenger'.

So, how to use `showSnackBar` now?

Comment: `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar)`
ull have to use the context of the scaffold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work with just replacing currentState with ScaffoldMessenger, either you need to make a ScaffoldMessengerState key and use it like

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState.showSnackBar(mySnackBar);
```

or you could give context give this way

`ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(YourSnackbar);`

It's all mentioned in their flutter docs, please refer and it also has migration guide

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger

Answer (score 1):

You can show `snackbar` this way :

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
  ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
  ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(state.message)));
```